# WPF DataGrid RowHeader databinding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, datatable, row

I have a DataGrid, bound to a DataTable. I want to display text in the RowHeader, to achieve something like this:

```
         Col0      Col1      Col2      Col3
Table |    1    |    3    |    5    |    6    |
Chair |    3    |    2    |    1    |    8    |
```

Is this possible and if so, how can I do this?

Comment: Do you really mean RowHeader, or did you meant to say ColumnHeader?

Answer (score 41):

I tried both answers, and neither worked for me. Essentially what I had to do was mix them together.

This works for me:

```
<DataGrid name="ui_dataGrid>
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                      AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, 
                                      Path=Item.Header}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

The trick is to find the ancestor `DataGridRow`, then Bind the `TextBlock.Text` attribute to its Item's property that you care about, in this case `Header` (easier said in XAML than English maybe).

Then in the .xaml.cs:

```
ui_dataGrid.ItemsSource = dataSource.Rows;
```

N.B. Each `Row` object has a `Header` property which is what I'm binding too.

Comment: Note that the path is really `item.propertyname`. _If someone might tell me how to figure out which properties there are available in runtime's datacontext, it'd help me a lot._

Comment: You could also use `Item[0]` to get the first column, instead of specify a name and use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16460193/5762332 to hide the first column

Answer (score 7):

2 ways to do it, the prev example almost had it but the binding would fail to resolve the property because the expression was missing "DataContext."

```
<DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.YourProperty}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>

        <!--your stuff-->
</DataGrid>
```

2nd way to do it is to create a converter to get the binding, parse it in the converter and spit out whatever string value you want:

```
<Views:DataGridRowDataContextToRowHeaderValueConverter x:Key="toRowHeaderValue"/>

<DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                       AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},
                       Converter={StaticResource toRowHeaderValue}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
```

Sample converter code:

```
public class DataGridRowDataContextToRowHeaderValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                           CultureInfo culture)
    {     
        var dataGridRow = (DataGridRow) value;
        var row = (GridModelExtensions.HourRow) dataGridRow.DataContext;
        return row.Days[0].Hour;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the rowheader template, something like this

```
<DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding YourProperty}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>

        //your stuff
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI, if you bind directly to a data table, then this binding text worked for me:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                  AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, 
                                  Path=Item.Row.Header}
```

Poked around a little bit and found that in the `Item.Row.Header` path, the path starts at the **DataGridRow**, the `Item` takes you to the **DataGridView**, and the `Row` takes you to the **DataRow**.

Again, if you bind directly to the data table.

Answer (score 0):

@michele: If I modify the Binding to:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.YourProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
```

then it almost works. The problem is that this results in the same row header for each row.

Comment: Ok, when I wrote YourProperty I meant you can bind the RowHeader to any property of a single row you add to the grid; feel free to provide a piece of your code, maybe i can help you further!

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there just change the AncestorType to **DataGridRow** instead of **DataGrid** then the row headers will be different for each row e.g.