# Wpf DataGrid RowHeader

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, rowheader

I am trying to use a `RowHeader` in a `wpf` `DataGrid` with no luck.

I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791929/wpf-datagrid-rowheader-databinding?rq=1)

My XAML code

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DataGrid Grid.Column="0"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Results}" Margin="5">
                <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,  
                                  AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},  
                                  Path=Item.Item1}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="LArmAngle"
                            Binding="{Binding Item2.LArmAngle}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="PropellerAngle"
                            Binding="{Binding Item2.PropellerAngle}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
...
</Grid>
```

The Results property is specified as follows

```
public ObservableCollection<Tuple<String, GeometryStateViewModel>> Results
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

I only see the two columns `LArmAngle` and `PropellerAngle` is the resulting `DataGrid`.
I would like to see the following:

```
            LArmAngle PropellerAngle
aStringHere     1          0.3 
aStringHere     1          0.3
```

Comment: You have define two columns only. So, what else you expect?

Comment: A RowHeader populated for the string in Item.Item1?

Comment: Your code works for me

Comment: @Shoe you can see the RowHeader string?

Comment: Yes, you might try putting static text in there to see if you can see text at all.

Comment: Same result with the static text. I used Text="text" and again I only see the two columns. Any ideas where to look for the bug?

Comment: Nothing special besides taking stuff out until it works. Take a look at your codebehind as well to see if there's something going on there. I also hope you are actually running the program and not just looking at the design view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to find why I can not display the RowHeader. As a workaround I added an additional column in the data grid to display the sting that I wanted.

```
...     
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Results}" Margin="5">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Algorithm"
                                Binding="{Binding Item1}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="LArmAngle"
                                Binding="{Binding Item2.LArmAngle}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="PropellerAngle"
                                Binding="{Binding Item2.PropellerAngle}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue as well.  The "HeaderVisibility" may be defaulting to column.

```
<DataGrid 
         Grid.Column="0" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Results}" 
         Margin="5"
         HeadersVisibility="All"
         >
```