# How to dynamically show two dimensional data in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a SQL Statement getting the following grouped data:

```
Name  |  Year  | Count
-----------------------
Adam  |  2015  |  2
Adam  |  2014  |  1
Adam  |  2013  |  5
Eva   |  2015  |  7
Eva   |  2014  |  4
```

I did not find any solution out there to dynamically fill a WPF DataGrid with the Year as column Header and the Name as Row Header by binding them to my ViewModel. Is the only posibility to create it by coding in the code behind?

```
        |  2013  |  2014   | 2015  
-----------------------------------
Adam    |   7    |    1    |   2
Eva     |   0    |    4    |   7
```

Comment: What have you tried? You'll just need to go throw it into a HeaderTemplate and RowHeaderTemplate.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisW. this hint helped me to find this here:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791929/wpf-datagrid-rowheader-databinding)

Comment: Good deal, glad you found your remedy. Come on back if you run into other issues.