# wpf adding row header in datagrid programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable

I need to add row header to my datagrid,I'm using a datatable, binding like this:

```
dg1.ItemsSource = Data.DefaultView;
```

Now, how can I add row header? this is my xaml:

```
<DataGrid Name="dg1"
          MinColumnWidth="19" MinRowHeight="19" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Data.DefaultView}" 
          FontFamily="B Nazanin" FontSize="14" 
          CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
          CanUserReorderColumns="False"
          CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
          Height="58" Margin="13,82,0,-83" Width="532" 
          UseLayoutRounding="False" IsReadOnly="True" LoadingRow="dg1_LoadingRow"
          >
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791929/wpf-datagrid-rowheader-databinding

Comment: this not working for me!!idk why?!!

Answer (score -1):

How to add a row:

```
DataGridName.Items.Add(new DataItem());
```

How to add a column:

```
DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn(); 
column.Header = "Column 1"; 
column.Binding = new Binding("Column1");
dataGridName.Columns.Add(column);
```

Comment: It's the code how to add a header in the DataGrid. And can you don't be crazy?

Comment: read my question, i said row header while I'm using datatable, it means I use datarow row=datatablename.newRow() to add rows,crazy!!