# DataGrid with header for row and column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I would like to create a WPF Datagrid that has got header for rows and column, accordingly to the following excel grid:

[image]

In particular, the blue cells are fixed, that means that I suppose they needs to be the headers.

Notice that I would like to create a List that contains each row, and T is as follows:

```
class T
{
    double ag;
    double fZero;
    double tcStar;
}
```

How to create it with a DataGrid?

Comment: Have you tried `DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle` Property ?

Comment: No, can you give a little sample please?

Comment: look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791929/wpf-datagrid-rowheader-databinding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate`
The `DataGrid` control has a `RowHeaderTemplate` property that defines the `DataTemplate` for the `DataGridRowHeader`.For columnheaders use `ColoumnHeaderStyle`.Check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.columnheaderstyle(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Country" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.Continent, 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

Actually this sample sets the corresponding continent for each countries displayed in the rows.I think this [link](http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/08/18/right-aligned-row-numbers-datagridrowheader-wpf/) may help you

Answer (score 1):

You can add column headers by using `DataGridTemplateColumn`.

```
  <DataGrid x:Name="dg" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ag" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        //add items
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Fo" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        //add items
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Tc" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        //add items
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

You can use `RowHeaderTemplate` to add row headers.